# Determining which t-test is right?

Tags: self-study, t-test

I have already solved this question, but I need some feedback.

> A new method for measuring blood pressure in laboratory mice using radiotelemetry has been proposed. How does this compare with the existing method? You apply both methods to a sample of 16 mice and use **________**.

I believe a matched-pairs *t*-test should go in the blank.
Am I right or wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like the simplest plausible answer to me. You definitely wouldn't want to use an independent-samples *t*-test to compare data sampled from the same set of 16 mice with two different methods used on each mouse, because that would ignore the (likely) correlations of measurements taken from the same mice.

Comment: "right or wrong" requires only a one-word answer, which by the usual policy on answers (that they be more than a sentence) means none of your questions of this form will be answerable in the answer space. Please at least *explain* your reasoning (not just the result of it), and try to phrase your question in such a way that a response can be more than 'right' or 'wrong'

Answer (score 1):

*I am answering this old question so it has an answer.*

Given that this is a 'fill the blank exercise', presumably aimed at a beginning student, and we have the `t-test` tag (suggesting the asker has been studying t-tests), then as the comment says a paired t-test seems like the simplest plausible answer.

Presumably, you would measure the blood pressures of the mice with the existing method, and again with the new method (one issue to consider is does the act of measuring blood pressure cause a change in blood pressure - e.g. stressing out the subject).

### How could we formulate the hypothesis?

Our null hypothesis could be that the population mean of the differences is $0$. Our alternate hypothesis would then be that the population mean of the differences is not $0$.

It might be interesting though to think about how the results of the test would be interpreted in practice and what the reason is for doing this test in the first place. Perhaps if you had strong reason to believe you would have a difference in one direction you might have a one sided hypothesis.

### What is an advantage of paired t-tests?

To flesh out this answer and give a bit more context. In a paired t-test we could think of each subject as having their own little control group - it could be themselves (as in this case), or maybe someone else like an identical twin. The advantage to this is that for each subject, all factors will be constant (except anything that changed between the time of measurement) and we (hopefully) have less variation in our sample than if we compare different people between different groups.

### Anything to be mindful of?

One thing to be mindful of with any repeated measures design is 'order effects'. This is best illustrated by an example. I ask my participants to do a task and measure their performance. I then apply some treatment, and ask them to do the task again. It might be the case that they perform better the second time they do the task - and this might be unrelated to the treatment - it could simply be because they have now seen and practiced the task once before.

Comment: One thing to add to this comprehensive answer (+1): if possible, and the treatment has no lasting effect,  half of the participants (mice) should be given the treatment in the second round, and the other half in the first round of the experiment. If properly randomized, this allows to asses and control for the 'order effect', at least if this is an additive effect. If the treatment has a lasting effect, one may use some participants as control that are not given any treatment other than repeating the task.